# Converting a generating function from fraction form to a power series

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Given a fraction $\frac{(1 + ax^{n})^{m}}{(1 + bx^{p})^{q}}$, how does one convert it to a series of the form $a_{0}x^{0} + a_{1}x^{1} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{3}x^{3} . . .$ ?

I was unable to find instructions for this, and I could use the information to to solve this problem:

> Given the equation $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + y_{1} + y_{2} = 6$,
>
> where $0 ≤ x_{i} ≤ 2$ and where $y_{i}$ is divisible by $3$,
>
> find the number of possible solutions in natural numbers by calculating the coefficient of $x^{6}$ in the generating function:
>
> $f(x) = (1 + x + x^{2})^{4} (1 + x^{3} + x^{6} + . . .)^{2}$.
>
> Hint:
>
> $1 + x^{3} + x^{6} + . . . = \frac{1}{1 - x^{3}};$
>
> $1 + x + x^{2} = \frac{1 - x^{3}}{1 - x}$.

Comment: Don't believe the first hint.  $1+x^3+x^6+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x^3}$

Comment: @Splutterwit, uh, right, let me reformulate that in the body of the question.

Comment: @saulspatz, why not?

Comment: @Megabyte216 Because it's incorrect.  I gave you the correct value in my prior comment.  It's just a geometric series.

Comment: @saulspatz, oh drat, I knew I'd end up writing something wrong with that LaTeX notation. I'm so sorry. Yeah, it was _my_ mistake. Good catch. I got distracted by a friend speaking, and it doesn't help that I was in the process of translating the math problem from Hebrew, which is written from right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the hints, we have:

$$1 + x^{3} + x^{6} + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - x^{3}}$$

and

$$1 + x + x^{2} = \frac{1 - x^{3}}{1 - x}$$

so

$$\begin{align}f(x) &= (1 + x + x^{2})^{4} (1 + x^{3} + x^{6} + \cdots)^{2}\\[1ex]&=\frac{(1 - x^{3})^4}{(1 - x)^4(1-x^3)^2}\\[1ex]&=\frac{(1 - x^{3})^2}{(1 - x)^4}\\[1ex]&=\frac{(1 - 2x^{3}+x^6)}{(1 - x)^4}\\[1ex]&=(1 - 2x^{3}+x^6)\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+3}{3}x^k\\[1ex]&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\binom{k+3}{3}-2\binom{k}{3}+\binom{k-3}{3}\right)x^k\tag{1}\end{align}$$

The penultimate step uses the negative binomial expansion:

$$(1-x)^{-4}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+3}{3}x^k$$

So the $x^6$ coefficient of $(1)$ is:

> $$\binom{9}{3}-2\binom{6}{3}+\binom{3}{3}=45\tag{Answer}$$

---

This method can be easily generalised by using the general binomial and negative binomial expansions:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k= 0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

and

$$(1-x)^{-m}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{k+m-1}{m-1}x^k$$

respectively.

Comment: Nice, thanks! So what you do is just expand those fractions and use a binomial expansion. Hm, somehow the result doesn't match the one I got from separation into cases. If $(y_{1},y_{2})=(0,6)∨(6,0)∨(3,3)$, then each $x_{i}=0$. That's $3\times1$ solutions. Next, if $(y_{1},y_{2})=(3,0)∨(0,3)$, then the x part of the equation is some 4-permutation of 1, 2. $P(2,4)=4\times3=12$. That's $12\times2$ solutions. Finally, if $(y_{1},y_{2})=(0,0)$, then the x part is some reordering of either (0, 2, 2, 2) or (1, 1, 2, 2). $P(1,4)+P(2,4)=10$. Total number of solutions: $37=3+12\times2+10$.

Comment: @Megabyte216. What about for $(y_1,y_2)=(3,0)\vee(0,3)$ then the $x$ part is some reordering of $(0,1,1,1)$? This makes $2\times P(1,4)=8$. Add that to your $37$ to get $45$. To answer your first question: yes, that's exactly right. It could get complicated in general but that's the basic idea, expand both binomials. If you have more factors on the denominator it can be useful to use partial fractions.

Comment: Oh right, now everything is in harmony. Yay!